# Asignar valor y que quede seleccionado (SET) a un <select> sin utilizar metodo "change()" con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web con `PHP, JQuery y MySQL`.

Tengo un formulario con varios  dependientes.  El tipico caso de deparamento, minicipio y vereda. Ese formulario se llena y se guarda bien en la base de datos. Hasta ahi no hay problema.

El problema es el siguiente: Hay un boton para ingresar a ese registro existente para editar la informacion.  Entonces, con `ajax`, busco el id que se selecciono y cargo en el formulario los datos almacenados. El probelma esta al momento de cargar el valor guardado en la base de datos (SET), en el componente SELECT (Departamento).  Me queda de la siguiente forma:

Cuando abro el select veo que el valor queda seleccionado (sombreado de azul), pero no queda en "frente" del Select (Departamento): Imagen 1

[image: Valor asignado a SELECT con JQuery]

Deberia quedar asi: Imagen 2

[image: Valor seleccionado en SELECT con Jquery]

La ides es utilizar un evento diferente a `CHANGE`, porque ese evento (change) ya lo estoy utilizando y cargaria los datos del select y la seleccion.

Estoy utilizando la siguiente instruccion:

`JQUERY`

```
 $("#Nombrecomponente option[value="18"]").attr("selected",true);
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que libreria utilizas para el componente de seleccion ?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta .. esta es la libreria que utilizo de JQUERY.<script src="../../assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Me refiero a la interfaz gráfica.Que otras librerias tienes referenciadas en el html ?

Comment: Bootstrap V3 - <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: El select que utilizas con campo para búsqueda incluido no pareciera el de bootstrap. Estas seguro no usar alguna otra librería para el componente select ?

Comment: Si tienes razon, disculpame. estoy utilizando Select2. <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de la librería select2 para disparar el evento que tome los cambios de opción seleccionada se debe ejecutar el método trigger pasando como parametro el evento change (https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options)

Podrias reemplazar la linea:

```
$("#Nombrecomponente option[value="18"]").attr("selected",true);
```

Por:

```
$('#Nombrecomponente').val('18');
$('#Nombrecomponente').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Anibal, pero la idea es NO utilizar el metodo Change, porque me quita la seleccion.  Ya tengo el change con la llenada de datos de la base de datos, entonces si lo utilizo vuelve y ejecuta ajax y llena el select y quita la seleccion.

Comment: Es necesario que cada vez que cambies la opción seleccionada se recargue la información ? Hay un "por que" para esto ?